# Dynamically add specific attr to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I created `valid-file` attribute using angular directive because file-input (with [bootstrap filestyle plugin](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/)) don't see `required` attribute :

```
    .directive('validFile',function(){
        return {
            require:'ngModel',
            link:function(scope,el,attrs,ngModel){
                //change event is fired when file is selected
                el.bind('change',function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
                        ngModel.$render();
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

I need to dynamically add or remove `valid-file` attribute.
If I use 
`$("input").attr("valid-file");`
nothing will change.
If I use `$("input").attr("valid-file",true);` it will add attribute `valid-file="true"` but validation will break.
Can you advice me something?
Here's plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Gcbb7r05VBTjbh9x5Ma8?p=preview

Comment: in demo it is working

Comment: try this:  http://plnkr.co/edit/rctRTK0hPTkzOAXCZR0U?p=preview

Comment: nope. I need <input valid-file> not <input valid-file="true"> . I tried also .prop() but result is the same.

Comment: Your result is the same.

Comment: Also tried to use $compile to add attr... but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.attr()` need 2 parameters if you want to set any attribute in any element.

ex. 
`$("input").attr("valid-file","");` // empty will also ok..or any value instead of empty

because only `$("input").attr("valid-file")` is used to get value of attribute "valid-file"

So you need 2 parameter in `.attr()` to set any attribute

Try this:  http://plnkr.co/edit/lSl3GdZrRAyFps5QOSlw?p=preview

```
 $("select").change(function(){
    if ($("select option:selected").val() == "0") {
      $("input").attr("valid-file",""); // try this
    } else {
      $("input").removeAttr("valid-file");
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="0">Add attr
  <option value="1">Delete attr
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, hope it will help!

Comment: It add attr as I needed but validation is still broken :D I use angular to validate and my angular knowledge is poor :D

Comment: @kipris ohh..sorry kipris i dont have knowledge of angular..otherwise i may help you :)